# Why can't logical operators be used with relational operators in Python?

Tags: python, if-statement, logical-operators

I am trying to compare if two different variables lie in two different ranges in Python using the logical operator '&' and the relational operator 'if'. The question might be a silly one and I am sure it will be down voted but even then why doesn't this code work?

**Code**

```
a = 2.0
b = 3.0

if 1 <= a <= 4 & 2 <= b <= 5:
    print 'Yes'

if 1 <= a <= 4:
    print 'Yes, a'

if 2 <= b <= 5:
    print 'Yes, b'
```

**Output**

```
Yes, a
Yes, b
```

And what is the best method to do such comparisons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`and` is boolean AND. `&` is bitwise AND.

Because bitwise AND has [higher precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) (i.e. it is more binding) than the `<=` operator, it gets evaluated first when you don't wrap the left and right boolean comparison expressions in parentheses.

So the evaluation is like:

`1 <= a <= 4 & 2 <= b <= 5`

`1 <= 2.0 <= (4 & 2) <= 3.0 <= 5`

`1 <= 2.0 <= 0 <= 3.0 <= 5`

Which is obviously `False`. What you want is:

`1 <= a <= 4 and 2 <= b <= 5`

And you don't need parentheses here because the`and` operator has lower precedence than `<=` so the left and right expressions will get evaluated first by default.

It's worth taking a look at the [operator precedence table](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence). You don't need to memorize it, but it's good for understanding all the Python operators and their general relationship to one another.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
>>> a = 2.0
>>> b = 3.0
>>> 
>>> if 1 <= a <= 4 & 2 <= b <= 5:
...     print 'Yes'
... 
>>> if 1 <= a <= 4 and 2 <= b <= 5:
...     print 'Yes'
... 
Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that `&` is a bitwise operator instead of a logical operator.

In python, logic operators consist of keyword `and`, `or` and `not`. In your case:

```
if 1 <= a <= 4 and 2 <= b <= 5:
    print 'Yes'
```

Answer (score 0):

`&` is a bitwise operator.Use **and** instead of &.

```
if 1 <= a <= 4 and 2 <= b <= 5:
    print 'Yes'
```